# What is wrong with my merge sort implementation refer to CLRS?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I tried to implement merge sort using C++, however, something went wrong. I have no idea what is wrong.

The following code is what I wrote based on CLRS. I think it is quite easy to understand the meaning.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void merge(vector<int>& nums, int p, int q, int r);
void mergeSort(vector<int>& nums, int p, int r){
    if (p < r) {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        mergeSort(nums, p, q);
        mergeSort(nums, q + 1, r);
        merge(nums, p, q, r);
    }
}
void merge(vector<int>& nums, int p, int q, int r) {
    int s1 = p, s2 = q + 1;
    vector<int> l1, l2;
    for (int i = s1; i <= q; i++) {
        l1.push_back(nums[i]);
    }
    for (int i = s2; i <= r; i++) {
        l2.push_back(nums[i]);
    }
    int left = 0, right = 0;
    int idx = 0;
    while (left < l1.size() && right < l2.size()) {
        if (l1[left] < l2[right]) {
            nums[idx] = l1[left++];
        }
        else {
            nums[idx] = l2[right++];
        }
        idx++;
    }
    while (left < l1.size()) {
        nums[idx++] = l1[left++];
    }
    while (right < l2.size()) {
        nums[idx++] = l2[right++];
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vect;
    vect.push_back(1);
    vect.push_back(3);
    vect.push_back(12);
    vect.push_back(23);
    vect.push_back(4);
    vect.push_back(11);
    vect.push_back(44);
    vect.push_back(322);
    mergeSort(vect, 0, vect.size() - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        cout << vect[i] << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

I want to use the program to sort some integers, however, it only shows many duplicate numbers. What's going on? I don't think there is a problem of the merge function.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to use a debugger. Step through the code line by line and compare what is actually happening against what you expect to be happening.

Comment: CLRS starts counting at 1, C++ starts at 0. That's a big thing that effects what the pseudocode they present will actually look like. I also don't see how it would be easy when you use variables like `p`. I don't know what that means. And given that others are just `q` and `r`, I don't think they mean anything, and you picked random letters instead of meaningful names. And to top it all off, if the meaning was so easy to understand, you probably should have been able to easily find the error yourself.

Comment: If you are allergic to debuggers, I highly recommend inserting some print statements.  The print statements will give you an annotated history of your program behaves.

Answer (score 0):

The code needs a one line fix:

```
    int idx = p;    // not idx = 0
```

---

Optimized top down using arrays from Wiki article (note bottom up is slightly faster):

```
void TopDownMerge(int A[], int bgn, int mid, int end, int B[])
{
int i, j, k;
    i = bgn, j = mid, k = bgn;
    while(1){
        if(A[i] <= A[j]){               // if left smaller
            B[k++] = A[i++];            //  copy left element
            if(i < mid)                 //  if not end of left run
                continue;               //    continue
            do                          //  else copy rest of right run
                B[k++] = A[j++];
            while(j < end);
            break;                      //   and break
        } else {                        // else right smaller
            B[k++] = A[j++];            //  copy right element
            if(j < end)                 //  if not end of right run
                continue;               //    continue
            do                          //  else copy rest of left run
                B[k++] = A[i++];
            while(i < mid);
            break;                      //   and break
        }
    }
}

void TopDownSplitMerge(int B[], int bgn, int end, int A[])
{
    if (end - bgn <= 1)                 // if run size == 1
        return;                         //   consider it sorted
    int mid = (end + bgn) / 2;
    TopDownSplitMerge(A, bgn, mid, B);
    TopDownSplitMerge(A, mid, end, B);
    TopDownMerge(B, bgn, mid, end, A);
}

void TopDownMergeSort(int A[], int n)   // n = size (not size-1)
{
    if(n < 2)
        return;
    int *B = new int [n];               // 1 time allocate and copy
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        B[i] = A[i];
    TopDownSplitMerge(B, 0, n, A);      // sort data from B[] into A[]
    delete B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Afterwards, I finally get to fix the bugs of my program. After modification, here is the code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> temp;
    vector<int> sortArray(vector<int>& nums) {
        temp.resize((int)nums.size(), 0);
        mergeSort(nums, 0, nums.size() - 1);
        return nums;
    }
    void mergeSort(vector<int>& nums, int start, int end) {
        if (start >= end)   return;
        int middle = (start + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(nums, start, middle);
        mergeSort(nums, middle + 1, end);
        merge(nums, start, middle, end);
    }
    void merge(vector<int>& nums, int leftStart, int middle, int rightEnd) {
        int leftEnd = middle;
        int rightStart = middle + 1;
        int i = leftStart, j = rightStart;
        int index = 0;
        while (i <= leftEnd && j <= rightEnd) {
            if (nums[i] < nums[j]) {
                temp[index] = nums[i++];
            }
            else {
                temp[index] = nums[j++];
            }
            index++;
        }
        while (i <= leftEnd) {
            temp[index++] = nums[i++];
        }
        while (j <= rightEnd) {
            temp[index++] = nums[j++];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rightEnd - leftStart + 1; i++) {
            nums[i + leftStart] = temp[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Here is something should be careful next time:

1. In the merge part, it is difficult to merge in place. It'd be better to use another temp array to store the merged results and update to the target array (nums in this case).
2. Readable identifers is very recommended (Although the pseudocode of CLRS may not use that part).
3. Need to use debuggers to find the bug of program {However, it takes like forever to load local variables of VS Code debugers.